# Is there a way to check what datatype a template is?

Tags: c++, template-classes

Say I have the following code:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
    int Hash<K, V>::hf(const K& key)
    {
        if(K == typeid(string))
        {
            return MurmurHash2(key.c_str(), key.size());
        }
        else
        {
            return key*2654435761;
        }

}
```

Is it possible to do this in some way? If not could you recommend a method to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: template specialisation?

Comment: @isedev, I would prefer overloading.

Comment: @isedev could you give an example of template specialization ive never used it before.

Comment: @SergeyA: wouldn't overloading introduce unnecessary code when `K` is not a `string` (inlining and optimisations apart)?

Comment: @Iriketurtles this may help explain what isedev writes of: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Comment: @lriketurtles: added a (hopefully correct) example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (partial) template specialisation:

```
// general case
template <typename K, typename V>
    int Hash<K, V>::hf(const K& key)
    {
        return key*2654435761;
    }

// string case
template <typename V>
    int Hash<std::string, V>::hf(const std::string& key)
    {
        return MurmurHash2(key.c_str(), key.size());
    }
```

Comment: Im getting some errors saying unable to match function definition to an existing deceleration

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways of doing it:

1) Template specialization (making a special case for a template argument (here: `std::string`))

```
template<typename K, typename V>
int Hash(const K& key)
{
    return key * 2654435761;
}

template<typename V>
int Hash(const std::string& key)
{
    return MurmurHash2(key.c_str(), key.size());
}
```

2) Using `typeid` to compare the types

```
template<typename K, typename V>
int Hash(const K& key)
{
    if (typeid(K).hash_code() == typeid(std::string).hash_code())
        return MurmurHash2(key.c_str(), key.size());
    return key * 2654435761;
}
```

Comment: This is different from actual question, when hf is member of the class. There is also no guarantee that comparing `typeid()` of the same type will yield true.

Comment: Thanks! `hash_code()` is guaranteed to be the same for the same types.